# Command button press cycles through a desired range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code to where on each command button press, the current time is put into the first cell in a range. Then on the next button click, the next cell in the range is filled with the current time, and so on. I cant figure out how to cycle through the desired range and place a time value at that cell on each button press.

I have a basic double For loop that goes through the entire range I want and populates all cells with the current time at once. I only want one cell to populate at a time with the current time on each button click, and I cant figure out how for the life of me.

code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 6 To 115
    For j = 3 To 5
        Cells(i, j).Value = Time
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: can we see your code? i.e. what you have done so far

Comment: yea , there is my basic for loop.   Im trying to mess with active cells to try and iterate through the range on each button press.   I think im a little out of my league though, haha.   Very new to coding in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it like that

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("C6:E115")

    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rg
        If Len(sngCell.Value) = 0 Then
            sngCell.Value = Time
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**Update**:

This solution should be faster but I think it will not be noticeable.

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Union(Range("C5"), Range("C6:E115"))

    Dim nextCell As Range
    Set nextCell = rg.Find("")
    If Not nextCell Is Nothing And nextCell.Address <> "$C$5" Then
        nextCell.Value = Time
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim emptyCellFound As Boolean
  Dim c As Range

  emptyCellFound = False 'not really needed. just for clarity

  For i = 6 To 115
    For j = 3 To 5
      Set c = Cells(i, j)
      If c.Value = "" And Not emptyCellFound Then
        c.Value = Time
        emptyCellFound = True
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent!   Exactly how I was hoping it would work.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works if any value is applied in any cell below row 114

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    [C6:E115].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1).Value = Time
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

..without a value below row 114 this works

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo weird
    [C6:E115].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1).Value = Time
    Exit Sub
weird:
    If [C115].End(xlUp).Row > 6 Then [C115].End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Time
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```